# Does anyone know of sources for ATA 206?

Tags: commercial-aviation

I have been seeing references to 206 ATA recently. However, it appears to be so new that very little Google indexed information is available.

Has anyone dealt with this particular  ATA chapter, and if so are there any publicly available resources?

---

**Please note:** I am not talking about [USS Pinola (ATA-206)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Pinola_(ATA-206)).

Comment: Are you asking about [USS Pinola (ATA-206)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Pinola_(ATA-206))?

Comment: Alas, no. That one does actually show up on web searches. I am asking about the  chapter in Airlines for America (formerly  Air Transport Association) spec 100 (or whichever actually has chapter 206).

Comment: Can you provide any more information about this ATA 206? Where is it referenced? What is the subject?

Comment: Wikipedia claims that the ATA-100 scheme was superceded fifteen years ago. If true, this makes it difficult to imagine that Chapter 206 could be very new. From what I can tell, the ATA-100 numbering system stopped at around 115, so 206 seems a leap forward. Maybe it's some sort of proprietary extension of the numbering scheme?

Comment: ATA 100 has been superseded by ATA iSpec 2200 (which is in fact a result of the merge of ATA 100 and ATA 2100). Neither in ATA 100 nor in ATA 2200 there's something such as a chapter 206.

Answer (score 2):

[Airlines for America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airlines_for_America) *(formerly known as Air Transport Association of America (ATA))* [maintains a website](https://publications.airlines.org/) for their publications and subscriptions. You can access all/several of their specification documents.

Spec 100 (Manufacturers' Technical Data) can be downloaded from [this page](https://publications.airlines.org/CommerceProductDetail.aspx?Product=33), by just paying <strike>an exorbitant</strike> a minimal fee of $650.

I am not sure which spec contains Chapter 206.

Comment: I guess you can keep paying the very reasonable fees until you find the spec you are looking for.

Comment: That got a chuckle

Comment: @user7632 If this answers your question, please mark it as answer.